# How Do I disable a button if the user is not enter any data in the input field in a AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Initially button is disable after enter the data in input field button is enable how to solve this issue in the AngularJS?

```js
            $scope.productKeyId  = [];
      var productKey     = [];
      $scope.user        = {};
       $scope.createAlbumDialog = function(event, productObj) {
                //Disable clicked button and other..
                //$(event.currentTarget).parents(".resetIt").toggleClass("fadeAndDisable", true);

                $scope.productKeyId  = productObj.keyId;
                $scope.albumName  =  $scope.user.userSearchInProduct;
                 console.log("productKey :: " + $scope.productKey + " albumName :: " + $scope.albumName);

                 var PRODUCT_DB_REF = firebase.database().ref('datastore/productsAlbum');

                 PRODUCT_DB_REF.push({
                    productKey          : [$scope.productKeyId],
                    albumName           : $scope.albumName,
                    sellerUserTypeKeyId : Number(AUTH.userTypeKeyId)
                 });
       //Disable clicked button and other..
       //$(event.currentTarget).parents(".resetIt").toggleClass("fadeAndDisable", false);
      }
```

```html
<div class="w3-center">
          <button type="button" rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-rose btn-xs" 
            ng-click="createAlbumDialog($event, productObj)">
            <i class="material-icons">add</i>Create Album
          </button>
      </div>
```

Comment: Format your code please, it is really hard to read

Answer (score 1):

You could put your input and your button in a `<form/>` and then add the `required` attribute on your input, and check if your form is valid in a `ng-disabled` on your button.

Something like this :

```
<form name=myForm>
   <input ng-model="yourModel" required/>
   <button ng-click="yourClickFunction()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">My Button</button>
</form>
```

Or if you don't want to use a `<form/>`you could still use the ng-disabled attribute on your button and check on your input's model like so :

```
<input ng-model="yourModel" required/>
<button ng-click="yourClickFunction()" ng-disabled="!yourModel.length">My Button</button>
```

If your input is empty then `yourModel.length ===0`which makes this statement falsy and disabling your button.

Comment: thank you sir, but without form it is possible or not?

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't use a form, but yeah you can. I updated my answer

Comment: Thank your sir  -ng-disabled="!yourModel.length" -   this condition is working.

Comment: Glad i could help you @kapilsoni ! Can you accept my anwser then ?